# how to erase an element hasn't a certain character in vector elements

Tags: c++, vector, erase

i found many answers for erase an element of vector has a certain character 
but i tried to make some of these solutions to erase the element which hasn't that character but dosen't work

```
 for(int k=0; k<temp.size();k++)
{
     while(temp[k].find_first_of("xX")!= string::npos)
     {
         temp.erase(temp.begin()+k);
     }
}
variables_print.push_back(temp);
```

here an example , these code erase the elements have char "xX" but i tried to make it  **temp[K].find_first_not_of("xX")** and doesn't work

also make it **temp[K].find_first_of("xX")== string::npos** and doesn't work

how to erase the elements haven't x or X characters

Comment: You need to provide MCVE, you also need to explain what do you mean by "doesn't work". Your code has `while` loop inside it, which I do not understand, and it also has a very serious issue - it is going to skip elements immediately after erased ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
auto newEnd = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const auto& s) { return s.find_first_of("xX") == std::string::npos; });
v.erase(newEnd, v.end());
```

`remove_if` moves all elements *not* matching the condition to front, replacing those that satisfy the it. The condition here is satisfied when the lambda given as the third argument returns true. `newEnd` is the iterator pointing to the first element after those that are not removed.

For example, if input is this: `{"aaa", "bbx", "ccc"}`, after call to `remove_if` the vector looks like this: `{"aaa", "ccc", <used to be bbx>}`.

The second line removes all elements starting from`newEnd`. So in example above, you end up with `{"aaa", "ccc"}`.

The condition here is a lambda which returns true for each element that contains neither `'x'` nor `'X'`.

This is the same condition you tried - and is correct one. Problem with your original code different.

Look at: `while(temp[k].find_first_of("xX")!= string::npos)`. If the string *does not* contain `X`, the body of this nested loop will not be executed and nothing gets removed. Also, you could replace the loop with a simple `if` statement.

There's another problem with the outer loop. You increment `k` each time, even if you've just removed an element. Consider this example: `{"x", "x"}`. When incrementing `k` each time, you will skip the second string and end up with `{"x"}`.

The corrected code looks would look like this:

```
for(size_t k=0; k<v.size(); )
{
     if(v[k].find_first_of("xX") == std::string::npos)
     {
         v.erase(v.begin()+k);
     }
     else
     {
          ++k;
     }
}
```

Compare this with the first version. It's not only shorter, but also leaves much less room for bugs.

As @Bob_ points out in comments, the first version is known as [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). It's a common thing to see in modern C++ (i. e. C++11 and newer), so it's worth getting used to it and using it.

Comment: While your code seems to be correct, it is not an answer - it doesn't educate OP, it doesn't explain what's wrong with OP code, it just gives a magic incantation

Comment: erase-remove was there well before C++11. Of course, C++11 made it easier with lambdas, but it was always possible and encouraged. Also it is worth noting that original code with your fix, while correct, suffers from terrible performance degradation.